# Summing numpy.ndarray fails when passed to a thread

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, numpy

I'm writing a Python script that interfaces to a frame grabber via a call to ctypes. It gets an image from the frame grabber as a pointer to a byte array. I then want to sum the array along one of the dimensions to plot a profile. This works fine when I do this in the same thread. But I want to hand off to a different thread for processing (so I can grab images as fast as possible). When I do this, the numpy.sum method seems to be silently overflowing internally, because the profiles I get back have negative numbers in them. Any idea what might be happening here? Here's a code fragment:

```
self.grablib.IC_SnapImage(self.hGrabber, 100) # 100 ms timeout
imgPtr = self.grablib.IC_GetImagePtr(self.hGrabber)
#imgPtr is returned as a char pointer, which will mess things up
imgPtr2 = ctypes.cast(imgPtr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte))
imgArray = np.ctypeslib.as_array(imgPtr2, (572, 768))
imgTime = datetime.now()
args = (imgArray, imgTime)
Thread(target=self.processImage, args=args).start()
```

And here's the offending code inside the processing thread:

```
# Another thread to actually do the processing, while the previous one gets another image
def processImage(self, imgArray, imgTime):
    iy = np.sum(imgArray[range(0, 572, 2)], 1, dtype=np.float)
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I put as the `dtype` argument in `sum`, the overflowing still happens. It's as if numpy's accumulator is defaulting to the wrong type, and not getting overruled by the `dtype` argument.

Comment: Could you make a reproducible test case?

Comment: Bit tricky without accessing the underlying library. I'll try!

Comment: Hmm, as usual the process of trying to provide a minimal test example seems to have aided me. I think the issue may be with casting to `c_byte` - instead it should be `c_uint8`. Like a fool, I thought that `c_byte` was unsigned. But it's not! I'll test this change on the actual script and post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, the fault was casting a char pointer to a `POINTER(ctypes.c_byte)`. Apparently `c_byte` is signed, which was where the confusion was arising from. Basically my script was adding up a load of negative numbers. Sorry numpy, it wasn't your fault this time! The offending line should have read:

```
imgPtr2 = ctypes.cast(imgPtr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8))
```

Clearly uint8 is an unsigned 8-bit integer, which is exactly what I wanted. I don't know why I didn't put that to begin with. (Also, I don't know why it only didn't work in a different thread - that's weird.)